# how do i separate custom cells b-table in bootstrap vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

The B-chart is in a component for me. I write a template for each cell individually.
Every time I call the component, I want to have only the template cells that contain the requirements of the corresponding sheet. how can I separate this? there are too many template cells in the component. I only want to call the js or vue file of the relevant sheet and have those template cells work.
   
I use component:

```
<TableComponent :items="[{ name: { first: 'John', last: 'Doe' }, sex: 'Male', age: 42 },
          { name: { first: 'Jane', last: 'Doe' }, sex: 'Female', age: 36 },
          { name: { first: 'Rubin', last: 'Kincade' }, sex: 'Male', age: 73 },
          { name: { first: 'Shirley', last: 'Partridge' }, sex: 'Female', age: 62 }]"
    :fields=" [
          // A virtual column that doesn't exist in items
          'index',
          // A column that needs custom formatting
          { key: 'name', label: 'Full Name' },
          // A regular column
          'age',
          // A regular column
          'sex',
          // A virtual column made up from two fields
          { key: 'nameage', label: 'First name and age' }
        ]"
  
   />
```

Table Component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-table small :fields="fields" :items="items" responsive="sm">
      <!-- A virtual column -->
      <template #cell(index)="data">
        {{ data.index + 1 }}
      </template>

      <!-- A custom formatted column -->
      <template #cell(name)="data">
        <b class="text-info">{{ data.value.last.toUpperCase() }}</b>, <b>{{ data.value.first }}</b>
      </template>

      <!-- A virtual composite column -->
      <template #cell(nameage)="data">
        {{ data.item.name.first }} is {{ data.item.age }} years old
      </template>

      <!-- Optional default data cell scoped slot -->
      <template #cell()="data">
        <i>{{ data.value }}</i>
      </template>
    </b-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
        fields:{
         type:Array
        },
       items:{
         type:Array
       },

      }
    }
</script>
```